# How can I rotate object in pixel grid properly?

Tags: javascript, math

I have an 2D grid made from 1D array with with and height property. In that grid I have a box object which I want to rotate by X amount of degrees.
I have used this formula to rotate each pixel of object in grid:

```
newX = floor(cos(angle)*x - sin(angle)*y)
newY = floor(sin(angle)*x + cos(angle)*y)
```

It works fine when the box is small but if the box is bigger I get some empty cells. How can I fill empty spaces witch should be filled.
Here is an example of box with width and height 10 and then rotated by 45 degrees:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform reverse mapping:

Walk through all pixels of result. You can use bounding box of rotated image and scan its lines.

For every pixel one get coordinates of corresponding source pixel. If they lie in valid range (source rectangle), then copy source color to result.

To get reverse mapping formula, just change angle sign (if you have pure rotation without shift)

```
oldx = cos(angle)*newx + sin(angle)*newy
oldy = -sin(angle)*newx + cos(angle)*newy
```

Comment: So this formula that you wrote get's me the original coordinance for color. How do I get coordinates for the empty spaces in grid. Sorry I need a bit of clarification this is what I have gotten so far from your formula: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/UTY8l2d)

Comment: Using this approach you won't have empty spaces at all, because you fill all pixels of rotated image.